# What does the abbreviation "SPINS" for the security protocol for WSN mean?

Tags: security, protocols

Since the protocol SPINS is as far as I understand it commonly spread I would like what exactly the abbreviation means in [the paper](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~adrian/projects/mc2001/mc2001.pdf) "SPINS: Security Protocols for Sensor Networks" by Perrig et al. he introduces the new protocol but with no word mentions what SPINS acutally means and I am assuming

**S** ecur **i** ty **P** rotocols for Se **ns** or Networks

**S** ecur **i** ty **P** rotocols for Se **n** sor Network **s**

**S** ecur **i** ty **P** rotocols for Sensor **N** etwork **s**

doesn't fit since the letters are not even in the right order. Does anyone have an idea what SPINS acutally means?

Comment: it is probably `Security Protocols in Networked Sensors`

Comment: the origin of the acronym may not be from English language